# How do you clear a textfield box after going back from a navigation stack?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

For example, my home login screen has two textfield boxes for username and password. After logging in, and going to my second view controller, I have a logout button. Pressing the logout button takes me back to the root view controller (log in screen). However, the textfields are still occupied by the username entries. Is there a way to clear that automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In viewWillAppear function insert: *yourTextField.text = ""* for both textfields controls. You could also put it in viewDidLoad but that may or may not work consistently depending on how you set up the navigation. If you are doing a straight segue to the second controller and returning it should be ok. This will also work on multiline textView type control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your login view controller is presenting your main view controller.  I don't believe there is an automatic way to wipe the text boxes, but you could always set them after you've verified the credentials, and before you present the main view.

The approach I have used does it automatically, because the login view gets dismissed, and a new one created if someone logs out and logs back in.  To do this, simply switch your current second view to be the root view, and present modally the login view.  When the login completes, you dismiss the login view and drop back to the main view.  A log out, would then trigger the login view modal again, which would be blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    mobileNoText.text = ""
    passwordText.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Login button IBAction, you have to add this code.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

   @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

     //Your other code goes here

     //Add this code at the end
     usernameTextField.text = ""  //clear the username text field
     passwordTextField.text = "" ////clear the password text field

        }
```

This will clear out the username and password text fields, when you logout. so you will see a clear login form.

Answer (score -1):

Inside viewWillAppear you can detect if it has appeared due to being pushed on or as a result of another view being popped off. This is assuming your login is the first controller in a chain.

```
if (!self.isMovingToParentViewController){
   // Clear fields
}
else{
   // Showing for first time
}
```

Then simply add code to zero out the login fields.